# Entries of representation matrix of linear map between tate module is integer?

Tags: modules, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $\phi:E_1\rightarrow E_2$ be an isogeny of elliptic curves. Then $\phi$ induces maps $\phi:E_1[l^n]\rightarrow E_2[l^n]$, and hence induces a $\mathbb{Z}_l$-linear map $\phi_l:T_l(E_1)\rightarrow T_l(E_2)$.

$\mathbb{Z}_l$-linear map are also seen as $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map(because $\mathbb{Z}$ is subring of $\mathbb{Z}_l$), then I believe all entries of representation matrix of $\phi_l$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Is the result (all entries of representation matrix of $\phi_l$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$)  and reasoning correct?

**P.S
Reaction to comments.**

・Here, $Tl(Ej)$ means $l$-adic Tate module of elliptic curve $Ej$, that is, inverse lim of $p^n$-torison points of elliptic curve.

・This question's goal is to prove that 'We can find basis whose representation matrix has all entries in Z'. So I don't know how to take the basis, and maybe there are no way to take such a basis. Firstly, I would like to clarify that is possible or not, if possible, I want the example of such a basis, if not possible, I want to prove we cannot take such a basis.

Comment: There is no reasoning in your question. What is $T_l(E_j)$ to you? Matrix in which basis?

Comment: Rephrasing the comment above: can you explain what do you mean by $T_l(E_j)$? Also, you're talking about a matrix, but it is not clear with respect to what basis this matrix is taken. Can you clarify this?

Comment: What's true is that there is an isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}(E_1, E_2)\otimes\mathbb Z_l \cong \mathrm{Hom}(T_l(E_1), T_l(E_2))$. This is a (hard!) theorem of Faltings.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Your comment is unclear to me. I think the game here is to prove that there is a basis of $T_l(E)$ such that every element of $End(E)$ (algebraic endomorphisms) is given by a $2\times 2$ integer matrix. There are 3 cases: $End(E)=\Bbb{Z}$, $\Bbb{Z}[a]$ or quaternion algebra. Up to a $1/\deg(\phi)$ term this will extend to the group of isogenies $E_1\to E_2$.

Comment: I added reaction to comments.